# Bootstrap navbar mega menu doesn't work on Asp.Net Core

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I want to use Bootstrap navbar mega menu dropdown in my layout from here:

https://bootstrap-menu.com/detail-megamenu.html

I downloaded the code and put it into my layout, but mega menu neither expands nor anything happens when I click on it. Aria-expanded is always be aria-expanded="false" in the chrome inspect section. What am I missing?

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - ECommerce.Web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap files (jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS) -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        @@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
            .navbar {
                padding-top: 0;
                padding-bottom: 0;
            }

                .navbar .has-megamenu {
                    position: static !important;
                }

                .navbar .megamenu {
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    padding: 20px;
                }

                .navbar .nav-link {
                    padding-top: 1rem;
                    padding-bottom: 1rem;
                }
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body class="bg-light">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">ECommerce.Web</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- ========================= SECTION CONTENT ========================= -->

    <div class="container">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">

                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a> </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> About </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Services </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Mega menu  </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu megamenu" role="menu">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="col-megamenu">
                                        <h6 class="title">Title Menu One</h6>
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>  <!-- col-megamenu.// -->
                                </div><!-- end col-3 -->
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="col-megamenu">
                                        <h6 class="title">Title Menu Two</h6>
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>  <!-- col-megamenu.// -->
                                </div><!-- end col-3 -->
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="col-megamenu">
                                        <h6 class="title">Title Menu Three</h6>
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>  <!-- col-megamenu.// -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="col-megamenu">
                                        <h6 class="title">Title Menu Four</h6>
                                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Custom Menu</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>  <!-- col-megamenu.// -->
                                </div><!-- end col-3 -->
                            </div><!-- end row -->
                        </div> <!-- dropdown-mega-menu.// -->
                    </li>
                </ul>


                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Menu item </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link  dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Submenu item 2 </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div> <!-- navbar-collapse.// -->

        </nav>

    </div><!-- container //  -->




    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - ECommerce.Web - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
    /// some script

    // jquery ready start
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // jQuery code

        //////////////////////// Prevent closing from click inside dropdown
        $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });


    }); // jquery end
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to remove the following code in `<head></head>`:

```
 <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap files (jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS) -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```